# how to return the file's path without the file's basename?

Tags: php

I have a long path for a file, for instance,

```
http://www.mysite.com/local/views/templates/home.php
```

and I use `basename()` to return the file itself only,

```
<?php echo basename($file);?>
```

But how can I return the file's path without the file's basename like the line below?

```
http://www.mysite.com/local/views/templates/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) (although it doesn't leave a trailing slash).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/9jIkW)**.